# Update a cookie value without changing its expiry date?

Tags: php, setcookie

Update a cookie value without changing its expiry date?

```
$c = $_COOKIE["count"];
$c++;
if (isset($_COOKIE["count"])) {
    setcookie("count", $c);
}
else
{
    setcookie("count", $c, time() + 86400, '/');
}
```

Comment: not possible, since there is no such thing as "updating" a cookie, its also not possible to receive the remaining ttl. What you could do tough sereialize your data & ttl and save them as value, then you can read them and set the new ttl & data accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can update a cookie's value without updating its expiry date is by adding the expiry date itself into the value; that's because a browser only sends you the names and values of the cookies.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['count'])) {
    list($exp, $val) = explode('|', $_COOKIE['count'], 2);
    ++$val;
} else {
    $exp = time() + 86400;
    $val = 1;
}
setcookie('count', "$exp|$val", $exp, '/');
```

Comment: @UZSTYLEGROUP You'd have to clear any existent cookies first, because the format would have changed.

Comment: Cookie value: 1353168251%7C1 What is it ?

Comment: @UZSTYLEGROUP It contains the timestamp (left of `%7C`) and the actual value on the right, i.e. `1`,

Comment: how to make limit.  `if(20 > $_COOKIE["count"]){ if (isset($_COOKIE['count'])) {
    list($exp, $val) = explode('|', $_COOKIE['count'], 2);
    ++$val;
} else {
    $exp = time() + 86400;
    $val = 1;
}
setcookie('count', "$exp|$val", $exp, '/'); readfile(file.mp3) }`

Comment: `$c` or `$val` are just variable names; rename where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - PHP doen't know when the cookie will expire nor dose javascript (unless you copy the expiry time *into* the cookie contents).

Answer (score 0):

You can save expiry date in other cookie. When you update your cookie, just read expiry date from it and use it in your update.